# Is it safe to keep metadata before malloc'd string in C?

Tags: c, string, memory, struct

I'm curious to know if keeping a header of metadata around a string would be safe and not implementation dependent?

I'm not sure if the following would work across platforms or if there is something that could cause to read the wrong `size` or `total` fields or if there would be a problem doing a `realloc` on the buffer?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int size;
    int total;
    char buf[];
} String;

int get_str_size(char *str){
    String *pointer = (void*)(str-sizeof (String));
    return pointer->size;
}

int get_str_total(char *str){
    String *pointer = (void*)(str-sizeof (String));
    return pointer->total;
}

char *init_string(int sz){
    size_t header_size = 1 + sz + sizeof(String);
    String *pointer = calloc(header_size, 1);

    pointer->total = 0;
    pointer->size = sz;

    return pointer->buf;
}

char *realloc_string(char *str, int sz){
    int old = get_str_size(str);
    int new = old + sz;

    String *pointer1 = (void*)(str-sizeof (String));
    size_t header_size = 1 + new + sizeof(String);
    String *pointer2 = realloc(pointer1, header_size);

    return pointer2->buf;
}

int main(void){
    char *str = NULL;
    str = init_string(10);

    printf("Length of str:%d\n", get_str_size(str));
    printf("Total malloc'd:%d\n", get_str_total(str));
    free(str - sizeof (String));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any problems. But I would added `free_string` function.

Comment: I think it's reasonably safe apart from lack of error checking. I think I'd make `init_string` and `realloc_string` return `NULL` if the allocation fails. Other things I'd do include renaming `init_string` to `alloc_string`, making `realloc_string` work the same as `init_string` when `str` is `NULL`, and add a `free_string` function that accepts a valid string or a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Note that `BSTR` strings in MS Windows do something similar to this; they have a 32-bit length prefix before the returned pointer.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the comments everyone.

Comment: That code looks fishy, but without a [mcve] and further inspection it is hard to point at it. It is obfuscated with the pointer arithmetics, error-prone and a maintenance nightmare. Use a more straight-forward approach, if not for anything else than writing undestandable code. And add error-checking!

Comment: If you're careful, it should work, but … if you aren't careful, you pass something that isn't one of these allocated strings to the code and all hell breaks loose.  I think you'd be better off with the type-safety that comes from passing `String *` around, rather than passing around `char *` values that might (or might not) point to the data of a `String` structure.

Comment: the `sz` in `realloc_string(char *str, int sz)` appears to only append to the existing size rather than re-state the new desired size which is what happens with `realloc()`.  Is that you intention?

Comment: Yes, creating a struct with metadata around the actual data is safe and should work on all platforms as long as the actual data is aligned properly. In this case since the data is an array of char (which can be aligned on any address) alignment is not an issue. As far as your code goes, you use an incomplete type which I wouldn't use (because I am not really familiar with incomplete types). Also I would prefer using the offsetof macro when converting between pointers to the String buf and the String type and the reverse. For example, String *pointer = (void*)(str-offsetof(String, buf));

Comment: @chux Good point, the intention is to resize `buf` in order to append a new string to what `buf` currently is holding. What do you mean with re-state the new desired size?

Comment: `realloc_string()` with "realloc" in its names does not suggest code is setting up for _appending_.  The `size` in `void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)` is the _new_ size. By "re-state", I mean `size` in `realloc()` "re-establishes" the allocated size.  Something I'd expect `sz` to do in  the similarly named function `realloc_string(char *str, int sz)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not safe.

It has no undefined behavior (UB) nor implementation defined behavior as so is *legal*, aside from a minor `int/size_t` issue.

Unfortunately code hides too much.  [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917272/is-it-safe-to-keep-metadata-before-mallocd-string-in-c?noredirect=1#comment69049074_40917272). Consider the following code that compiles, yet invokes UB.

```
printf("%d\n", get_str_size("Hello Word"));
```

The set of functions would be better using the type `String` as arguments rather than `char *`.  That is what type checking is for.

---

Minor problems.

C *strings* are arrays.  Array indexing is best using type `size_t`.  `int` may be too narrow.

```
String *String_copy(const char *src) {
  size_t len = strlen(src);
  //                         v-v Overflow potential
  String *dest = init_string(len);
  ...
  return dest;
}
```

Following *could* `int` overflow.  Re-order to prevent.

```
//                      v----v  int math
// size_t header_size = 1 + sz + sizeof(String);
size_t header_size = sz + sizeof(String) + 1;
// or 
size_t header_size = sizeof(String) + sz + 1;
```

Code lacks other functions that should complement the set. [@Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917272/is-it-safe-to-keep-metadata-before-mallocd-string-in-c?noredirect=1#comment69047089_40917272)

There is lack of error checking, but assume that is for simplified code presentation.